# How to reload data for a single tableview cell using RXSwift

Tags: swift, tableview, rx-swift

I have a tableview whose cells are bound to a listItemRelay like so:

```
viewModel?.listItemsRelay
        .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .userInitiated))
        .share()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .bind(to: cardTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CardCell.identifier, cellType: CardCell.self))({ [weak self] index, listItem, cell in
            self?.update(cell: cell, at: index, with: listItem)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Now if one of the listItems have changed and I want to update just that cell. How would I do that here, I'm kind of new to RXSwift.

Comment: the `subscribeOn` and `share` do nothing in this context and should be removed. Do your list item object have any sort of id value?

Comment: I have inherited this code, and I'm a newbie when it comes to RXSwift. I'm not sure what share() does and I assumed subscribeOn was to make something happen on a background thread. ListItem doesn't have any ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to use [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) which will only update the cells that actually change.

A home grown solution is to use a different observable that the cells observe to determine what their contents should be:

```
viewModel?.listItemIdsRelay
    .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
    .bind(to: cardTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CardCell.identifier, cellType: CardCell.self))({ [unowned self] index, id, cell in
        self.viewModel!.listItemsRelay
            .compactMap { $0[id] }
            .bind { listItem in
                self.update(cell: cell, at: index, with: listItem)
            }
            .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The `listItemIdsRelay` tells the tableView what list items to display and only updates when an item is added or removed from the array. The cells observe the `listItemsRelay` and update whenever the list item they are observing updates.